# Make python enter password when running a csh script

Tags: python, scripting, passwords, root, csh

I'm writing a python script that executes a csh script in Solaris 10. The csh script prompts the user for the root password (which I know) but I'm not sure how to make the python script answer the prompt with the password. Is this possible? Here is what I'm using to execute the csh script:

```
import commands

commands.getoutput('server stop')
```

Comment: I had left out PIPE, the new version works...

Comment: First time to see commands in use.  BTW -- you can use the getpass module to grab a password from command line without displaying it.

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)

Comment: [Obligatory rebuttal to the "csh bashing" link](http://copilotco.com/mail-archives/kplug.2004/msg01005.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) module. It is designed to deal with interactive programs, which seems to be your case.

Oh, and remember that hard-encoding root's password in a shell or python script is potentially a security hole :D

Comment: Yeah, pexpect was the way to go... I posted the answer at the bottom of this thread.

Answer (score 5):

Use [subprocess](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-subprocess.html).  Call Popen() to create your process and use communicate() to send it text.  Sorry, forgot to include the PIPE..

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(['server', 'stop'], stdin=PIPE)

proc.communicate('password')
```

You would do better do avoid the password and try a scheme like sudo and sudoers.  Pexpect, mentioned elsewhere, is not part of the standard library.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'll continue to investigate popen though.

Comment: I get the same response when using the PIPE like you recommend here. The script stops with the Password: prompt.

Comment: I don't think that this works because the csh script does 
exec su root -c "$cmd0 $*"
to try to su to root. The su would be a different process than the 'server stop' script.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('server stop')
child.expect_exact('Password:')

child.sendline('password')

print "Stopping the servers..."

index = child.expect_exact(['Server processes successfully stopped.', 'Server is not running...'], 60)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Did the trick! Pexpect rules!

Answer (score 1):

Add `input=` in `proc.communicate()` make it run, for guys who like to use standard lib.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(['server', 'stop'], stdin=PIPE)
proc.communicate(input='password')
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to pass it as a parameter.  something like:

```
commands.getoutput('server stop -p password')
```

Comment: our server stop script doesn't have a -p flag and won't likely be getting one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work better:

```
import popen2

(stdout, stdin) = popen2.popen2('server stop')

stdin.write("password")
```

But it's not 100% yet. Even though "password" is the correct password I'm still getting su: Sorry back from the csh script when it's trying to su to root.

Comment: I think you inverted stdin and stdout.

Comment: Nope, from the API: Returns the file objects (child_stdout, child_stdin)

Comment: Just some FYI -- popen2 is "Deprecated since version 2.6: This module is obsolete. Use the subprocess module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section."

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. I switched my code back to the subprocess module. Thanks!

Comment: @darrick: I incorrectly referred to os.popen2 instead of popen2.popen2. Strangely enough, the order of stdin and stdout is different between the two libraries...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to answer the Password question in the python script I'm just going to run the script as root. This question is still unanswered but I guess I'll just do it this way for now.

Comment: Would you please clean up and consolidate your answers?