# Enter an ssh password using the standard python library (not pexpect)

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

Related questions that are essentially asking the same thing, but have answers that don't work for me:

[Make python enter password when running a csh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230845/make-python-enter-password-when-running-a-csh-script)

[How to interact with ssh using subprocess module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433660/how-to-interact-with-ssh-using-subprocess-module)

[How to execute a process remotely using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946946/how-to-execute-a-process-remotely-using-python)

I want to ssh into a remote machine and run one command. For example:

```
ssh <user>@<ipv6-link-local-addr>%eth0 sudo service fooService status
```

The problem is that I'm trying to do this through a python script with only the standard libraries (no `pexpect`). I've been trying to get this to work using the `subprocess` module, but calling `communicate` always blocks when requesting a password, even though I supplied the password as an argument to `communicate`. For example:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
        [
            "ssh",
            "{testUser1}@{testHost1}%eth0".format(**locals()),
            "sudo service cassandra status"],
        shell=False,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
a, b = proc.communicate(input=testPasswd1)
print "a:", a, "b:", b
print "return code: ", proc.returncode
```

I've tried a number of variants of the above, as well (e.g., removing "input=", adding/removing `subprocess.PIPE` assignments to `stdout` and `sterr`). However, the result is always the same prompt:

```
ubuntu@<ipv6-link-local-addr>%eth0's password:
```

Am I missing something? Or is there another way to achieve this using the python standard libraries?

Comment: Did you try what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21433723/2073595) suggests? That works fine for me in a Linux environment. If you're on Windows, I think you may be out of luck...

Comment: You need to supply the password twice, once for ssh on the client side and once for sudo on the server side. _How to interact with ssh using subprocess module_ looked reasonable to me and could be modified for the sudo part... what about it didn't work for you?

Comment: @tdelaney, There's no password for sudo on the server. It seems that the "How to interact..." solution may work, but I need to get the output of one of the commands, and a simple read is returning nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is just an adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21433723/2073595) by Torxed, which I recommend you go upvote. It simply adds the ability to capture the output of the command you execute on the remote server.

```
import pty
from os import waitpid, execv, read, write

class ssh():
    def __init__(self, host, execute='echo "done" > /root/testing.txt', 
                 askpass=False, user='root', password=b'SuperSecurePassword'):
        self.exec_ = execute
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.askpass = askpass
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        command = [
                '/usr/bin/ssh',
                self.user+'@'+self.host,
                '-o', 'NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1',
                self.exec_,
        ]

        # PID = 0 for child, and the PID of the child for the parent    
        pid, child_fd = pty.fork()

        if not pid: # Child process
            # Replace child process with our SSH process
            execv(command[0], command)

        ## if we havn't setup pub-key authentication
        ## we can loop for a password promt and "insert" the password.
        while self.askpass:
            try:
                output = read(child_fd, 1024).strip()
            except:
                break
            lower = output.lower()
            # Write the password
            if b'password:' in lower:
                write(child_fd, self.password + b'\n')
                break
            elif b'are you sure you want to continue connecting' in lower:
                # Adding key to known_hosts
                write(child_fd, b'yes\n')
            else:
                print('Error:',output)

        # See if there's more output to read after the password has been sent,
        # And capture it in a list.
        output = []
        while True:
            try:
                output.append(read(child_fd, 1024).strip())
            except:
                break

        waitpid(pid, 0)
        return ''.join(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = ssh("some ip", execute="ls -R /etc", askpass=True)
    print s.run()
```

Output:

```
/etc:
adduser.conf
adjtime
aliases
alternatives
apm
apt
bash.bashrc
bash_completion.d
<and so on>
```